# Decode UTF8 String to Latin

Tags: .net, encoding

I am trying to transform a UTF8 string to Latin characters.

Here's a example of how I am trying to achieve this:

```
string sUnicode ="Peneda-GerÃªs";
string result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sUnicode)));

MessageBox.Show(result);
```

The string return is the same? No change?

What am i missing?

If I go to this site

http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

and put the same text, it gets decode correctly to "Peneda-Gerês";

Comment: You are converting UTF-8 to UTF-8. Why would that ever show different strings?

Comment: I'd prefer to put the data in text files, and not in the source code. However, this looks like a broken UTF-8 (it's "encoded" to UTF-8 "twice"), and it's thus a broken byte sequence that's not exactly great to put inside in a C# string. Why don't you use an external tool to fix the broken text?

Comment: A .NET string is always encoded in Unicode (UTF-16), so your original string isn't UTF-8... Encoding only matters if you're reading from or writing to a stream (or if you convert the string to/from a byte array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source string is in ISO-8859-1

Run this and pick the correct encoder:

```
 string sUnicode = "Peneda-GerÃªs";
 foreach (var enc in Encoding.GetEncodings())
 {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}"
        , Encoding.UTF8.GetString(enc.GetEncoding().GetBytes(sUnicode))
        , enc.Name);
 }
```

Or to be spot on:

```
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
     Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(sUnicode));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting from unicode to utf8 to unicode. So the result is the same as the source.

```
       byte[] byteAr = {
                            (byte) 'P', (byte) 'e', (byte) 'n', (byte) 'e', (byte) 'd', (byte) 'a', (byte) '-',
                            (byte) 'G', (byte) 'e', (byte) 'r', (byte) 'Ã', (byte) 'ª', (byte) 's'
                        };

       var result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, byteAr));
```