# wrong encoding - xml numeric replacement is misinterpreted

Tags: .net, xml, encoding

I have xml-files that represent emails exported from a mail client. Unfortunately, when I try to read these files, the special characters are not displayed as the original characters were displayed.

I am trying to get this to read correctly in a client that I write in .Net.

Example: I get the following numeric replacement:

```
&#195;&#161;
```

This gets interpreted as:

```
Ã¡
```

While the original/expected value is:

```
ú
```

**A perhaps better example:**

```
Ta&#195;&#176; eftir er av &#195;&#161;rinum ber t&#195;&#179; til at logga &#195;&#161;
```

this gets interpreted as:

```
TaÃ° eftir er av Ã¡rinum ber tÃ³ til at logga Ã¡
```

The original/expected value is:

```
Tað eftir er av árinum ber tó til at logga á
```

I can observe that the problem seems to be, that .Net interprets Ã° as being two seperate characters, while the in reality represent one character.

I believe that I should be able to use this website to translate the interpreted value into the expected value (although not the exact characters I get): http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

But I am unable to get it correctly displayed in .Net.

```
x.Load(
  New StreamReader(
    File.Open("content.xml", FileMode.Open),
    Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), True
  )
)
```

This doesn't make a difference. If I try Encoding.Unicode then it fails to read the file (Error: Data at the root level is invalid)

Comment: Why would you expect two numeric replacements to be parsed as a single character? The numeric replacements are for *character* entities, not *bytes*. TL;DR: I believe your XML is incorrect, not .NET's handling.

Comment: Perhaps I could manually take the two decimal values 195 and 161 and convert to hex, this would become c3 and ba which is the UTF-8 hex value for the character ú. But isn't this conversion functionality built into .net somehow?

Comment: I think you've missed my point. The XML handling in .NET is doing exactly what it should be doing. If you want to represent U+00FA in XML, it should be represented as `&#250;` or `&#xfa;`. The number in the entity is a code point, as specified here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references - it's *not* meant to be "a byte that's part of an encoded representation of a character".

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure - It's just that every non-english character in the xml document is represented by 2 numeric representations. 195 161 = ú, 195 176 = ð, etc. It's possible that the XML is incorrect, but it's what I have to work with...

Comment: It's not just *possible* that the XML is incorrect - that's simply the case. Whatever produced it is broken. While you *could* try to work around it, that would break other cases with *correct* XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I commented before I saw your comment (both times). Will try a workaround then. The XML files from that client are _always_ like this so if these are broken, I will **not** need to parse _correct_ XML files.

Comment: @Andras - please, for your own sake: rather than trying to repair bad XML sent to you by a client, try to persuade your client to send you good XML instead. The stuff you are getting is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5130065/1113421

Ended up first loading the document in UTF-8, and then on the XML nodes that I needed, I converted them on-the-fly:

VB code

```
Dim x As New XmlDocument

x.Load(New StreamReader(File.Open("content.xml", FileMode.Open), Encoding.UTF8, True))

Dim nl As XmlNodeList = x.SelectNodes("product/HEADER/object")

  For Each nd As XmlNode In nl
    Dim result As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(nd.InnerText))
    Me.txtTemporaryTextbox.Text += result & vbCrLf
  Next
```

This gave me the correct interpretation of the foreign characters in the **nd.InnerText**.

Thanks @JonSkeet for elaboration and links that pointed me in the right direction, for further digging.

Comment: When loading XML from a byte stream (such as a file), it is not necessary to specify the character encoding. Just let the XML engine find out the encoding. When loading the file, don't use a character reader, use a byte stream.